# Unable to connect using SSH keys

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, ssh-keys

I am trying to connect to my linux server using the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I then do:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh myusername@myserver_ip 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

I then go to my remote server and see that a "authorized_keys" file has been created. However when i try doing, "ssh myusername@myserver_ip", it is still prompting me for a password?

Why???

Comment: Try with `ssh -vvv myusername@myserver_ip` to see more details.

Comment: You can check /var/log/auth.log or /var/log/secure on the server side. You can check your sshd configuration : RSAAuthentication yes, PubkeyAuthentication yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok First of all make sure you have this options enabled in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
    RSAAuthentication yes
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    AuthorizedKeysFlle %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Second, in order to copy the key from ServerA(where you generated the key) to ServerB(where you want to log in) use the following command:

```
    ssh-copy-id your_username@your_serverB_Ip
```

If by any chance ServerA doesnt have ssh-copy-id command, in ServerA copy the first line of your key WITHOUT the last 2 characters, then paste it in the ServerB Authorized_Keys file.  After that type yourself the missing characters from the line you just copied and the first one from line 2, this will prevent adding a "new line" between the first and second line of the key while pasting it from ServerA to ServerB. Repeat with the 3rd line

Answer (score 1):

Verify the ownership and permissions on your `~/.ssh` directory and its contents:

```
$ sudo chown -R <user> ~/.ssh
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

Comment: didn't work......

Comment: Well you're going to need to post more details then.

Comment: Did you do this on the server side ?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check the sshd_config to ensure that these are enabled:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Once those are set to 'yes' then you will need to restart ssh.